# Can Raspberry pi 4 get faster deluge download speeds than 1.5MB/s?

Tags: deluge

My Pc is downloading torrents on utorrent at 10MB/s, but deluge on RP4 gets about 1.5MB/s. Is this a limitation of the pi 4 or should I try other clients and settings? Old posts say limited ram of older pi's can cause this but I have the 4 4GB of ram.  I'm using an external USB HD for writes. **What top speeds for torrents are other people getting on RP4?**

Related: [1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46574/deluge-fluctuating-download-speeds?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I was connected with both wifi and network and turning off wifi forced the network internet connection which quintupled the internet speed test and solved the problem.